# Capture the parent link and child link as one into the Label paramater seperated with a colon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to achieve the following: 
Capture the mega menu link that's being clicked. If the link is a sub link, capture the parent link and child link as one into the Label paramater seperated with a colon.

This is the jsbin link to the HTML:
http://jsbin.com/kuliberefi/edit?html,output

I have managed to get the following code to console log the li's that I click on, but I am stuck on getting the parent link of the category. eg. When I go into the Mens section and click on shirts its meant to console log 'Mens: Shirts'.

my code:

```
$(".megaMenuList li").mousedown(function () {
     var value = $(this).attr('href');
     console.log(value);     
});
```

Thank you to anyone that can give me some advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the values in the URL, @gurvinder372 answer will do. If you want the actual values printed on your screen this solution will work.

```js
$(function(){

  $('.megaMenuList li a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      
      // get the text of the link clicked
      var subcat = $(this).text();
      
      // find the H2 that is on top of this megaMenuList
      var cat = $(this).closest('.megaMenuList').find( "h2" ).text()  ;  
      
      // output your cat & subcat
      if( cat ){
        console.log( subcat + ' : ' + cat );
      } else {
        console.log( subcat );
      }
  }); 

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="megaMenuList">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/womens/shirts/products">Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="/womens/dresses/products">Dresses</a></li>
        <li><a href="/womens/trousers/products">Trousers</a></li>
        <li><a href="/womens/skirts/products">Skirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="/womens/socks/products">Socks</a></li>
        <li><a href="/womens/underwear/products">Underwear</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="megaMenuList">
    <h2>Clothing</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/womens/shirts/products">Shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="/womens/dresses/products">Dresses</a></li>
        <li><a href="/womens/trousers/products">Trousers</a></li>
        <li><a href="/womens/skirts/products">Skirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="/womens/socks/products">Socks</a></li>
        <li><a href="/womens/underwear/products">Underwear</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="megaMenuList">
    <h2>Accessories</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/womens/jewelry/products">Jewelry</a></li>
        <li><a href="/womens/handbags/products">Handbags</a></li>
        <li><a href="/womens/shoes/products">Shoes</a></li>
        <li><a href="/womens/tights/products">Tights</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the `href` value and take second and third item (first one will be empty). [Updated bin](http://jsbin.com/pijicanuqa/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
$(".megaMenuList a").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var value = $(this).attr( "href" );
     var items = value.split("/");
     console.log( items[1] + " : " + items[2] );     
});
```